# C# thread safety for class instances

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am learning C# and I am confused with the thread safety of the copies of the class instances as below:

```
eg:
  classA objA;
  classA objB = objA;

  objA.field1 = value2; //do I need lock around modification of field1?

  //let say we pass the objB to another thread
  objB.field1 = value1 //do I need a lock for objB because of the modification of field1?
```

I am confused because coming from the background of C++, the class in C# is the reference type. If both objA and objB refer to the same memory underlying, then I would need a lock to protect the simultaneous writing to the field1. Could someone confirm with this or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mention your C++ background so perhaps you could think of your C# code as this C++ code:

```
classA objA;
classA &objB = objA; //note reference

objA.field1 = value2; //do I need lock around modification of field1?
                      //Answer : yes if someone else has access to the object
```

You should lock your object if modified/mutated by multiple threads.  That can be done easily using a property rather than a public field. Or using a simple method.

There may be times when modifying a primitive type does not require a lock.  But locking is the simplest and safest solution to most situations regarding concurrent access/mutation.

```
//let say we pass the objB to another thread
//do I need a lock for objB because of the modification of field1?
Thread newThread = new Thread((classB b) => b.field1 = value1);
```

Yes, providing the object is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. According to the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) the following types are atomic:
`bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float,` and reference types.

If field1 is one of those or a reference you don't need a lock if you don't have any further dependencies.

Comment: Atomicity and thread safety are usually two different issues. But I'm not a C# guru ...

Comment: Yes, if you have dependencies between other reads or writes. But in this (probably simplified) example where you only have one write you don't need locking to get consistency. In most real cases you do.